# How to count number of date between two days MySQL

Tags: mysql

On my mysql table I keep date as datetime. (eg: 2013-11-09 11:15:58), I want to write mysql Query to get number of dates to given date. can someone help me to write this..

eg:
Given date: 2014-01-19 10:15:15

On table 'date_added' has: 2013-11-09 11:15:58

is it possible to get number of dates using mysql query, like COUNT(), SUM()

Comment: No. It's simply not possible. That would be like maths or something.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it shows absolutely no research effort/

Answer (score 0):

To find number of records on a specific date of given timestamp, use `date_format` or `date` functions on the field to filter by `date`.

```
select 
    date( date_added ) dt, 
    count( date_added ) dt_cnt 
from my_table
group by 
    date_format( date_added, '%Y-%m-%d' );
```

Alternatively, you can also use `date` function to extract date part from a datetime column.

```
select 
    date( date_added ) dt, 
    count( date_added ) dt_cnt 
from my_table
group by 
    date( date_added );
```

And if you want to count based on date part of an input datetime value then, use

```
select 
    date( '2014-01-19 10:15:15' ) dt, 
    count( date_added ) dt_cnt 
from my_table
where 
    date( date_added ) = date( '2014-01-19 10:15:15' );
```

**Refer to**:

- [*DATE(expr)*](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date)

  - Extract the date part of a date or datetime expression
- [*DATE_FORMAT(date,format)*](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format)

  - Format date as specified

Comment: When OP said *count of date*, you tell me if it is possible or correct to count by *datetime*?

Answer (score 0):

I think your using TIMESTAMP to use this [method](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff)

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY,'2003-02-01','2003-05-01') from tablename;
```

if you want to count following this code:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM a1 WHERE '2014-03-01';
```